# Change a value in column b based on when a value in column A changes

Tags: sql, case

I have a data set that looks like the below as a simple example

```
Date    Description
1/1/24  Testing
1/1/24  Testing
1/2/24  Apple
1/2/24  Apple
```

What I need to do in SQL is the the end result to look like the below.  In short I only need the description on the first row of each date.

```
Date    Description
1/1/24  Testing
1/1/24  
1/2/24  Apple
1/2/24
```

I have tried to think through to see if I could use a case expression but that really doesn't address my issue as I can change column b based on something in column a but I don't know what to put in the case when statement to address to make any secondary same date or more to be blank.

Comment: SQL has no concept of row-order (at least in storage) so this isn't something you would do in SQL (though it is possible to do this using window-functions); instead, you would do this in your application-layer (or your reporting engine). Do you have a _good reason_ for wanting to do this in SQL?

Comment: What about if I was to use a row number and partition it by date and then a case statement could only display the description when there is a 1  (assuming the row number would reset to 1 everytime there is a change in the date).    I never have written the partition piece so that's where I would need some help at as just been reading about it.

Comment: Just use LEAD/LAG windows functions, as @Dai suggested, to work out when the value changes and a CASE statement to define what the column value should be when there is/isn’t a change

Comment: You (probably) mean case _expressions_.

Comment: You normally solve this in your presentation layer, not your database. Solving issues at the right layer usually makes the problem easier, and maintainability better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this one if you can use CTE.

```sql
declare @Data as table (Dates date, Description nvarchar(50));

insert @Data (Dates, Description)
values
('1/1/24','Testing'),
('1/1/24','Testing'),
('1/2/24','Apple'),
('1/2/24','Apple');

with table_nameCTE AS (  
  select *, row_number() over (partition by Dates, Description order by Dates) as RN  
  from @Data  
)
select Dates
  , case when RN = 1 then Description else '' end as Description
from table_nameCTE
```